# How to remove: "LaTeX Error: Unicode character (U+2009)"

Tags: errors, overleaf, unicode

I'm writing a document in Latex using Overleaf. I'm not able to remove the error: `"LaTeX Error: Unicode character (U+2009)"`. The error is due to the statement of the following:

`where $V{_p{_h}}$ is  phase velocity of the desired Lamb Wave mode and $V_L$ is longitudinal velocity of the incident wave in the coupling media.`

How can I correct the error?

Comment: Hi, have you tried finding this thing using the unicode converter: https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html ?

Comment: This already looks wrong: `$V{_p{_h}}$` what is this suppose to mean?

Comment: Seems you've input a thinspace character somewhere. You should use `\,` instead. However, you can add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,}` to your document preamble to this replacement automatically.

Comment: the error is not due to Tex markup you have added that character

Answer (score 1):

See

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?is%20%E2%80%89phase

You have an invisible Unicode space character between `is` and `phase`  simply delete and use a normal space.

Note you only showed a fragment of the error message. The full message highlights exactly where the character is (via the line break)

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character   (U+2009)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 where $V{_p{_h}}$ is  
                            phase velocity of the desired Lamb Wave mode and...

?
```